# If 2 versions of a plugin are stored in eclipse plugin directory, how does eclipse determine which to use

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In `Eclipse` plugin directory I have plugin jar called `someplugin.1.jar` dated yesterday and `someplugin.2.jar` dated today.

How does eclipse decide which one to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the JAR is irrelevant; if they are bundle/plugin JARs, it's the contents of their `manifest.mf` files that Eclipse uses to determine the ID and version of the bundle/plugin they contain.

If they are the same plugin ID but different versions, then which one is loaded is based on expressed dependencies of other plugins. It's possible that they *both* can be loaded (assuming the plugin is **not** marked as a singleton), if there are other plugins that depend on the different versions (although that is rare).

If the plugin is a singleton (most are, because they have to be in order to contribute to extension points), then I'm pretty sure the one with the higher version will be chosen if there are no dependencies that dictate otherwise. If both JARs have the same plugin ID and version then I don't think there is deterministic behavior about which one will show up in runtime.